# How check Internet-connection in Android?

Tags: java, android

What are the ways to check your Internet connection in Android.

And what is the difference between them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure that there isn't already an answer on StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create method like below.

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

and call it wherever you want. Put it in **IF - ELSE** condition so you can check for connection.

Or if you want to call this method through out your project then you can create one static class like below.

```
public class ConnectivityDetector {

    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it like below shown code in every class wherever you want.

```
if (ConnectivityDetector.isConnectingToInternet(Test.this)) {
         // do your stuff
} else {
         // Alert dialog that says, No Internet connection 
}
```

Also make sure that you have the required permission to monitor the network state. You need to add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope this will help you.